# What is the better method to define a marker position

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In google maps API, to specify the position of a marker with the position (0,0) we can use

- position : new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)

OR

- position : {lat:0, lng:0}

The two expressions work fine ...

My questions :

- What is the difference between the two expressions ?
- Which one is better to use.

Thank you

Comment: They are both equivalent (although [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral) objects can't be used everywhere that [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) objects can be used (yet)).  Use whichever is simplest for you.

Comment: So helpful, Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The difference:**
The first uses a LatLng-instance(with methods `lat` and `lng`), the 2nd is a LatLngLiteral, an object-literal with properties `lat` and `lng`.
Both are completely different,  `Marker.setPosition` accepts both kinds of objects.

**Which one is better to use:**

It depends on your opinion what is "better", just some points:

- the API first checks if the position is a LatLng. When it does, it uses the LatLng, otherwise it converts the LatLngLiteral  into a LatLng. So it's clear, for performance it's better to use a LatLng.
- the LatLngLiteral may be used without the maps-API(e.g. you may store it without a already loaded maps-API, you also may transport it via JSON)
- LatLngs are accepted by any object/method of the maps-API which expects a coordinate, but there are different methods/objects which do not accept a LatLngLiteral, so it may be better to use always LatLngs to avoid errors.